# How to use selenium internetexplorerdriver with proxy c#

Tags: c#, selenium, proxy

this code works:

```
        var ieOptions = new InternetExplorerOptions();
        ieOptions.ForceCreateProcessApi = true;
        ieOptions.BrowserCommandLineArguments = "-private";
        Proxy proxy = new Proxy()
        {
            Kind = ProxyKind.Manual,
            HttpProxy = "1.1.1.1:8080",
            SslProxy = "1.1.1.1:8080",
        };
        ieOptions.Proxy = proxy;
        IWebDriver driver = new InternetExplorerDriver(ieOptions);
```

This code does not:

```
        var ieOptions = new InternetExplorerOptions();
        ieOptions.ForceCreateProcessApi = true;
        ieOptions.BrowserCommandLineArguments = "-private";
        Proxy proxy = new Proxy()
        {
            Kind = ProxyKind.Manual,
            SocksProxy = "1.1.1.1:1080",
        };
        ieOptions.Proxy = proxy;
        IWebDriver driver = new InternetExplorerDriver(ieOptions);
```

checking IE settings and socks is simply not populated there.
is it a bug?

Answer (score 1):

I believe you are missing

```
options.UsePerProcessProxy = true;
options.Proxy = proxy;
IWebDriver driver = new InternetExplorerDriver(options);
```

to force the `webdriver` to use `proxy`

Second block of code does not tell the browser to use proxy anywhere. How `driver` is going to know if you do not specify?

Comment: in a second code I pasted just a differences. I edited my post to be more exact. `UsePerProcessProxy`- Gets or sets a value indicating whether to use the supplied Proxy settings on a per-process basis, not updating the system installed proxy setting. - it's a bit different as I'm not trying to set a per-process proxy, I`m trying to set a "system proxy". (IE default).